# Con-cat/append streams of string in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, append

[image]

How would I do the example shown on the image in c. i.e concat/append the strings to one string. The strings are coming out from char *array;. Would the below function work? Thanks

```
ptr = strcat( s1, s2 );
```

I would like to print the joined string then

```
printf("the string is = %s ",joinedstring);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11583613/971127

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` expects `s1` to be long enough to fit the result of all concatenations. This means the destination must be 17-characters long, because the string has 16 characters, and you need one more `char` for the null terminator.

In addition, the result must start with an empty string, like this:

```
char res[17] = {0};
strcat(res, "this");
strcat(res, ":");
strcat(res, "is");
... // and so on
```